# Angularjs 1.3.15 ng-model in directive not binding on IE but works on Chrome

Tags: angularjs

I am using angular 1.3.15 version with my own directive to create form elements. The model values get updated when i run this on chrome and firefox but ie10 the forms values dont get updated on the model.

The same code works on an older version of Angular. I tried with 1.2.1 and it works as expected.

Angular 1.3.15 Version of the code here http://goo.gl/Qzk5iA

Angular 1.2.1 Version of the code here http://goo.gl/WYE6pG

```
var myAppModule = angular.module('myApp', []);   
 myAppModule.controller("TodoCtrl",function($scope) {    
        $scope.tree = [];
        $scope.nodeMap = [];
        $scope.items = [{name:"Sudha",group:"",visibility:"visible",value:{value:"as"}},{name:"Gautam",group:"",visibility:"visible",value:{value:"as"}}];
        $scope.foo = function()
        {
            for(var i=0;i<$scope.items.length;i++)
            {
                var item = $scope.items[i];
                console.log(item.name+" "+item.value.value);
            }
        }
    }).directive("ppField",["$compile", function($compile) {
         return {
            replace:true,
            require:'ngModel',
            scope:{
                parameter :'=parameter',        
                ngModel : '='
            },
            restrict: 'AE',
            link : function($scope, $element, $attrs) {   

                var field = '<input   id=\''+$scope.parameter.name+'\'  name=\''+$scope.parameter.name+'\'  type="text" ng-model="parameter.value.value" class="form-control input-sm">';
                var newInput = angular.element(field);            
                var $e =$compile(newInput)($scope);
                $element.append($e);
            }
         };
    }]);
```

The html is a simple ng-repeat with the directive inside of it. On clicking the done button the model values are printed to the console. Chrome works as expected but IE shows the initial values.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.15/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div ng-app="myApp">   
      <div ng-controller="TodoCtrl">
          <button ng-click="foo()">Done</button>
            <div data-drag-enabled="false">
                    <div ng-repeat="parameter in items">      
                      <label for="{{parameter.name}}" class="col-sm-4 control-label labelBreak" data-ng-click="showTooltip(node)">                    
                        {{parameter.name}}
                      </label>
                      <div class="col-sm-8 fieldDiv" ng-model="fieldCount">
                          <pp-field ng-model="parameter.value" parameter="parameter" disabled="disabled"></pp-field>
                      </div>
                    </div>

            </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Are you sure you aren't running in compatibility mode?

Comment: @KevinB Yes pretty sure i am not on compatibility view. Browser Mode : IE10 Document Mode:Standards

Comment: I checked with different versions of Angular 1.3.1. It works as expected until 1.3.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the disabled="Disabled" from the html, IE disables all child elements if the parent is disabled, that is probably why the binding does not work. Chrome does not disable like IE.

Try this